# How to Total Columns as a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have an SQL Query:

```
Select Location, net_sales, total_visits, Avg_money_per_visit
from Daily_Sales
where day = @day
Group By Location
```

That is run in VB.NET and stored in a datatable  From there, I convert it to HTML and send as the body of an email.

Output

```
Location       Net_Sales      Total Visits   AVG Money Per Visit
1               100                5                  20            
2                50                2                  25
3               200                2                  100
```

What I'd like the output to look like with Totals:

```
Location       Net_Sales      Total Visits   AVG Money Per Visit
1               100                5                  20            
2                50                2                  25
3               200                2                  100
Total:          350                9                  38.89
```

How can I get the sum column in either SQL, or The datatable prior to converting to HTML.

Here is how i'm converting to HTML:

```
Public Function DataTableToHTMLTable(ByVal inTable As DataTable) As String
        Dim dString As New StringBuilder
        dString.Append("<table border=""1"" cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"">")
        dString.Append(GetHeader(inTable))
        dString.Append(GetBody(inTable))
        dString.Append("</table>")
        Return dString.ToString
    End Function

    Private Function GetHeader(ByVal dTable As DataTable) As String
        Dim dString As New StringBuilder

        dString.Append("<thead><tr>")
        For Each dColumn As DataColumn In dTable.Columns
            dString.AppendFormat("<th>{0}</th>", dColumn.ColumnName)
        Next
        dString.Append("</tr></thead>")

        Return dString.ToString
    End Function

    Private Function GetBody(ByVal dTable As DataTable) As String
        Dim dString As New StringBuilder

        dString.Append("<tbody>")

        For Each dRow As DataRow In dTable.Rows
            dString.Append("<tr>")
            For dCount As Integer = 0 To dTable.Columns.Count - 1
                dString.AppendFormat("<td td align='center'>{0}</td>", dRow(dCount))
            Next
            dString.Append("</tr>")
        Next
        dString.Append("</tbody>")

        Return dString.ToString()
    End Function
```

Comment: UNION ALL your query to the same query without the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming 'Location' is a varchar field, you can append the total field to your base query to return the sum from DB itself:

```
--<<Original Query>>
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    'Total:'
    , sum(net_sales)
    , sum(total_visits)
    , sum(Avg_money_per_visit)
from
    Daily_Sales
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use WITH ROLLUP in your GROUP BY.  Also, you can throw a GROUPING() in there to label the total.

```
Select 
CASE WHEN GROUPING(Location) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE CAST(location AS VARCHAR(2)) END AS location
, SUM(net_sales) AS net_sales
, SUM(total_visits) AS total_visits
, CAST(AVG(Avg_money_per_visit) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS avg_money_per_visit
from Daily_Sales
where day = @day
Group By Location WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Wouldn't this require me to add the rest of the select columns to the group by clause?  At least that looks like to me

Comment: @Shmewnix nope, but if you want precision for the `avg_money_per_visit`  the decimal wont work. This will: `CAST(ROUND(CAST(SUM(avg_money_per_visit) AS NUMERIC(10,2))/COUNT(avg_money_per_visit),2) AS NUMERIC(10,2)) AS avg_money_per_visit`. As the average is: `48.33` not `48`. Some may want it down to the ***penny*** :)

Comment: Interesting - Thanks I'll give it a try.  Another question - How does this change if you do a query made up of sub-queries?  Does the RollUP still work the same with that?